# Select2: Searching not working with external json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

0.13) to load a json with country names.
I can show and select the data correctly, but the searching is not working.

Everytime I type something it always returns all the values and not the ones I'm searching for.

This is my code:

```
$("#reg_afi_nac").select2({
       width: '100%',
       placeholder: 'Ingrese la nacionalidad',
       language: 'es',
       ajax: {
           url: "<?php echo base_url('assets/json/nacionalidades.json') ?>",
           dataType: "json",
           type: "POST",
           data: function(params) {
               return {
                   q: params.term, // search term
               };
           },
           processResults: function(data) {
               return {
                   results: $.map(data, function(item) {
                       return {
                           text: item.text,
                           id: item.text
                       }
                   })
               };
           },

           cache: true,
       },

   });
```

Comment: select2 expects that the remote server will do the filtering based on the provided search term. Obviously a raw JSON file cannot do that. You'll need a PHP script as an intermediary, to filter the data.

Comment: Ohh, I have the raw JSON, any ideas on how the php script should be? or how to search for it, couldn't find anything in the select2 documentation

Comment: select2 won't tell you how to filter your own data - it can depend on too many factors. The PHP script needs to read the `q` parameter in the $_POST data, load the JSON from the file and decode it to an (associative) array, and use the search term to filter the data on whatever properties of the JSON you want, get the results, encode those into a JSON object in the format select2 expects, and echo them. I can't see your JSON or how you want to search inside it so it's difficult to be more specific. P.S. You might find it simpler to hold the data in a database instead and use SQL to filter it.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, I figured that the most simple option was to convert my json file to a js file and give the array a name,

Then I just imported that script and used the array as direct source for the select.

var data = $.map(NACIONALIDADES, function(obj) {
        obj.text = obj.text.toUpperCase();
        obj.id = obj.text.toUpperCase();
        return obj;
    });

    $("#reg_afi_nac").select2({
        data: data,
        width: '100%',
    })

Comment: Indeed. If you use client-side data, select2 will do the filtering. Glad you solved it.